# ActiveRecord find with association details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose I am doing matchmaking of users and games.
I have models containing users and games.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :games
```

Games can have many users, users can be playing many games.  Because of HASBM I have a table called games_users too.

I want to search and find games that are waiting for players, which do not also contain the username of the player (i.e. I don't want to add the same player to a game twice...)

I want something like this:

@game = Game.find_by_status(Status::WAITING_USERS, :condition => "game.users.doesnt_contain('username=player')

But I'm not sure how to do it?

**Update:**

Using jdl's solution, I got the code to run, but get items that I tried to exclude returned in the results.  Here's my test code:

```
logger.debug "Excluding user: #{@user.id}"
games = Game.excluding_user(@user)
if (games != nil && games.count > 0)
  @game = Game.find(games[0].id)
  games[0].users.each {
   |u|
   logger.debug "returned game user: #{u.id}"
  }
end
```

(the above code also begs 2 questions.... - how do I get a result of just one game instead of an array, and how to I get a non-readonly version of it; that's why I do the second Game.find...)

And here's the output in the log:

```
Excluding user: 2
  Game Load (0.3ms)   SELECT `games`.* FROM `games` left outer join games_users gu on gu.game_id = games.id WHERE (gu.game_id is null or gu.user_id != 2) 
  Game Columns (1.0ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `games`
  SQL (0.2ms)   SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM `games` left outer join games_users gu on gu.game_id = games.id WHERE (gu.game_id is null or gu.user_id != 2) 
  Game Load (0.1ms)   SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE (`games`.`id` = 3) 
  games_users Columns (6.8ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `games_users`
  User Load (0.9ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` INNER JOIN `games_users` ON `users`.id = `games_users`.user_id WHERE (`games_users`.game_id = 3 ) 
returned game user: 1
returned game user: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named scopes are your friend here.

For example:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  named_scope :for_status, lambda {|s| {:conditions => {:status => s}}}
  named_scope :excluding_user, lambda {|u| {:conditions => ["gu.game_id is null or gu.game_id not in (select game_id from games_users where user_id = ?) ", u.id], :joins => "left outer join games_users gu on gu.game_id = games.id", :group => "games.id" }}
end
```

This will let you do things like the following:

```
user = User.first  # Or whoever.
games_in_progress = Game.for_status("playing")
games_in_progress_for_others = Game.excluding_user(user).for_status("playing")
# etc...
```

Also, since you say that you're new to Rails, you might not realize that these named scopes will also work when you're traversing associations.  For example:

```
user = User.first
users_games_in_waiting = user.games.for_status("waiting")
```

Comment: Looks promising, but that syntax is pretty opaque to this new rails user without much sql experience.  I get the following horrible message back from mysql when I try it:
  Game Load (0.0ms)   Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.id WHERE ((`games`.`status` = 2) AND (gu.game_id is null or gu.user_id != 2))' at line 1: SELECT `games`.* FROM `games` left outer join games_users gu on gu.game_id = 'games'.id WHERE ((`games`.`status` = 2) AND (gu.game_id is null or gu.user_id != 2))

Comment: ..and
Exception: Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.id WHERE ((`games`.`status` = 2) AND (gu.game_id is null or gu.user_id != 2))' at line 1: SELECT `games`.* FROM `games`  left outer join games_users gu on gu.game_id = 'games'.id WHERE ((`games`.`status` = 2) AND (gu.game_id is null or gu.user_id != 2))

Comment: Weird. That was tested code with sqlite, but maybe MySQL is doing something odd with it. I'll fire it up on there and see.

Comment: See above. MySQL was barfing on the quoted table name.

Comment: This is looking good; the code runs now, but like the other user's solution it is returning games that include the user id I was trying to exclude.  Perhaps I have something else up here... Thanks for taking the time to try mysql!

Comment: It's returning games with the user you don't want, even when you use the .excluding_user scope? I'm not seeing that here, so if that's the case, please post your code and a log of the queries being generated.

Comment: I've updated the initial post with current status, much easier than using the comments!

Comment: (I'd really like to understand what the excluding_user named scope is doing - I don't really understand what the join is doing, or how the 'gu' variable is created')

Comment: Please try the latest version above. It requires that your db supports subselects, which is a safe bet if you recently installed MySQL. Otherwise, I would advise making 2 scopes -- 1 for empty games, and 1 for games without the user.

"gu" is just an alias that makes the SQL easier to read/write. You could explicitly name the table each time. For info on the join, etc. check the MySQL docs.

Comment: Your updated sample worked great...! thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier in a two step process.

Step 1 get the list of games the user is involved in:

```
games_playing = user.games.for_status('playing')
```

Step 2 get a list of open games for the player:

```
open_games = Game.for_status('waiting').not_including(games_playing)
```

Where you have an additional named scope in the `Game` class:

```
named_scope :not_including, lambda {|g| { :conditions => ["id not in (?) ", g] }}
```

Comment: This method worked for me too; and is a little easier to follow than the jdl's.. I suspect this is slower though.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute your query the way you want and use the slice method to remove the user from the results (but this is not very good performance wise if the user is added to a lot of games already)

sort of like this

```
   a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
   a.slice!(1)     #=> "b"
   a               #=> ["a", "c"]
```

Or write a custom sql query (using find_by_sql and use != user_id to exclude that from the query.

I am not sure if there is a "pure" Rails way to do it in the find itself without using a custom query.

**edit:**

You could do something like this, pretty "Railsy",

```
@game = Game.find_by_status(Status::WAITING_USERS, :conditions => ["id NOT IN #{user_id}"])
```

Or for multiple users, an array

```
@game = Game.find_by_status(Status::WAITING_USERS, :conditions => ["id NOT IN (?)", [1,2,3]])
```

Let me know if that works out for you :-)

Comment: I was a afraid of that.  Not sure how to construct the sql, but will look into it.

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm new to Stackoverflow and not quite sure how to make sure you see my edit. So hopefully this comment will notify you and you can check it out :)

Comment: @Bitterzoet #{user_id} should be @user.id in my case, right?  I tried that, but MySQL complains that 'id NOT IN 2' is not valid syntax

Comment: ... using the second form works with MySQL, but for some reason it doesn't exclude the user and I get a game with the passed user returned.

Comment: No if you use #{user.id} it will still read out the @user.id.

try ["id NOT IN (#{user.id})"]

Comment: That works, but problem remains that it doesn't seem to exclude the user properly...